# Indirect modification of overloaded property in codeigniter model when editing variable set in helper

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling, models, helper

I have setup a login helper within my codeigniter setup.

I get the codeigniter instance, call a model, and set some variables.

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

I then use `$CI->load->vars($data);` to make the variables available in all my models and views.

One of the variables is as follows `$data->errors=array();`

The idea being that if there is an error in my model I can set an error
e.g `if($query->num_rows()!='1'){$this->error[]="This message does not exist !";}`

Then in my controllers I can check if this variable is populated and if it is display the error.

This is however throwing up the error

> Message: Indirect modification of overloaded property Mail_model::$error has no effect

This error is going over my head. I've done some research into the error but cant find any explanation in lehmans terms with an applicable solution.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loaded the $CI variable as a reference to itself - with =&

You have then loaded the variables through the reference - because you used $CI->load->vars()

There is no need to load the $data into the $CI reference.

If you want to pass messages between models and controllers (such as error messages) - then trying to use global variables is probably not the best way.

The best option for CodeIgniter is [Flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) - this is the exact scenario why flashdata exists. You can read all about it in the CI [userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).

Comment: How can one use flashdata here? If there is an error, it sets flash data.. but this can only be used after the next server request ergo it is of no use..?

The controller calls a model, which sets an error as flash data.. but there is no further server request to then access this set value..

Comment: "but this can only be used after the next server request ergo it is of no use..?" - WRONG - it can be used UNTIL the next server request. Therefore you can set flashdata - and then use it immediately after

Comment: p.s. I know this is true - because it is exactly what I do.

Comment: It is not :P I just created a seperate empty controller and model to test this. If i load a model from my controller and in the model function set a variable as a flash var, then directly below this call in my controller echo this set flash var, it does not work. If however i refresh the page, the flash var is outputted..